# Jest is failing because of missing property in Expo (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, expo

Test suite failed to run:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'linkingUri' of undefined
>          at Object. (node_modules/expo/src/Constants.js:18:29) at Object.
>   (node_modules/expo/src/Logs.js:94:228) at Object.
>   (node_modules/expo/src/Expo.js:3:1)

Any one have the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The Expo SDK (as well as React Native packages with native code) read fields from `ReactNative.NativeModules`. In this case, Constants.js in the Expo SDK is trying to read from `ReactNative.NativeModules.ExponentConstants.linkingUri`, but since one of the objects in that chain is not defined -- after all, you're running this code in Node and not in Expo -- you're getting that TypeError.

---

### jest-expo

There is a package called [`jest-expo`](https://github.com/expo/jest-expo), which mocks out `ReactNative.NativeModules.ExponentConstants` and much more for Jest tests.

To use `jest-expo` (as of version 22.x), first remove `jest` or `jest-cli` from your package.json file's dependencies since `jest-expo` will import the correct version of Jest for you. For example:

```
yarn remove jest
```

---

Next, install `jest-expo` in your project:

```
yarn add --dev jest-expo
```

**Note:** If you're using an older version of the Expo SDK, make sure to use the corresponding version of `jest-expo`. You can't use `jest-expo` for Expo SDK 21 with a project built for SDK 22, for example.

---

Finally, add this to your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "node_modules/.bin/jest"
},
"jest": {
  "preset": "jest-expo"
}
```

Run your tests with `yarn test`.

---

These specific instructions might change over time but they communicate the gist of how to use `jest-expo`. The GitHub README for the project is one of the best places to look as it's closer to the source of truth.